# Reading text file into a linked list C++

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, file-handling, singly-linked-list

I have been trying to read a text file into a linked list. The only problem I face is that it wont read all the entries.

My class for Student:

```
class Student // Student class which hold student data
{
private:
    char Name[15];
    char Roll_no[8];
    int Serial_no, FSC_marks, Entry_test_marks;
public:
    void Print() // Print student data
    {
        cout << "\n" << Serial_no << "\t"<< Roll_no << " " << Name << "\t" <<  FSC_marks << "\t\t" << Entry_test_marks << endl;
    }

    void Read(fstream &infile)
    {
        infile >> Serial_no;
        infile >> Roll_no ;
        infile.get(Name,15);
        infile >> FSC_marks >> Entry_test_marks; 
    }
}
```

Class for Linked List

```
class LinkList // Linked List 
{
    struct Node // structure for Node containing Object of Student class
    {
        Student info;
        Node* link;
    };
    Node* head;
    
public:
    
    Linklist() // default constructor
    {
        head = NULL;
    }
};
```

Here's the printing fucntion:

```
void LinkList::print() // Prints List of Students
{
    Node* temp = head;
        
    if(temp != NULL)
    {
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            temp->info.Print();
            temp = temp->link;
        }
        
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Here's the Reading function:

```
void LinkList::Readfromfile()
{
    fstream File;
    File.open("Lab_15.txt" , ios::in);
    File.seekg(40);
    
    while(File)
    {
        Node* newnode = new Node();
        newnode->info.Read(File);
        newnode->link = NULL;
        
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = newnode;
        }
            
        else
        {
            Node* temp = head;
            while(temp->link != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->link;
            }
                
        temp->link = newnode;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how the text file looks like:

```
Serial_No   Roll_No Name    F.Sc    Entry_Test
1   19I-0777    Jame#s moriarty777  70
2   19I-0789    Sherlock    734 80
3   19I-0860    Holmes      843 88
4   19I-0884    Dave Bautista   732 54
6   20I-1003    Barry Allen#    712 32
7   20I-1004    Clark kent  632 15
8   20I-1015    Adam        658 67
9   20I-1034    Ahmad hussain   734 55
10  20I-1041    Bill ga#tes 811 98
11  20I-1054    Trump       888 45
13  20I-1057    Donald duck 576 67
14  20I-1903    Faiza#n Shahid  789 34
15  20I-1904    Umair Shahid    567 55
16  20I-1909    Abdullah    123 67
17  20I-1915    Ali         300 45
```

In the original text file i have about 20 entries, but my code only reads about 13. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can actually just replace head with new node and point that to old head. Or, if you care about order, keep track of `tail`, so you don't have to traverse the whole list each time.

Comment: Is the code stopping at reading the firt 13 lines, or is it stopping after printing the first 13 lines?

Comment: Also, you don't leave room for the *null character* at the end of each char array (ie `Student::Name` and `Student::Roll_no`), which may cause problems. What is on line 14 in the file? Have you tried printing the contents of the list while reading the file? Since it's only 20 lines, can you post the whole content of it? I think the header of the file is not 40 characters long.

Comment: @gthanop The code only reads the first 13 lines. Output is same if I print the file while reading it. Increasing size of Roll No changes nothing, however increasing size of Name resulted in only about 7 entries being printed. I have updated the text file. (Also there are a few '#' in the Names, I am required to remove them, I can search for the character but how should I delete/remove a specific character from a word)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact you didn't provide a destructor and so are leaking memory, and you aren't using the STL which would save you some time and would have probably worked on its own, I see no obvious mistake in the algorithm.

Here's where I would search to spot the bug:

1. Why are you skipping 40 characters at the beginning of the file (`File.seekg(40);`)?
2. You're mixing operator `>>` with the `get` function. I have had bugs result from that.
3. Check the file is actually correct and you didn't mistype something.

Also as others have noted it may be quicker to just reassign the head when you insert the new node instead of walking the list again.

Comment: I haven't learned/studied STL yet. I am skipping the first line (40 character) as it contains title such as Serial number, Name etc. and I don't want to print it. For Reading Name only the get function is working. I cant use >> because the Names consist of 2 words, and for some reason getline function is also failing. And yes the file is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `LinkList` constructor's name.

You name the (supposed) constructor to `Linklist` instead of `LinkList` which makes it not a constructor, which results in unitialized `head` pointer.

Other than that, you may still be reading the file inproperly. Don't forget to close the `File` after you are done with it.

#### Edit 1: answering your [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68420029/reading-text-file-into-a-linked-list-c/68422531#comment120929045_68422531)

Make sure you follow some reference on `fstream`s, such as:

1. `istream::get` method (`fstream` inherits `istream`) reads until either `n - 1` characters are reached, or until the delimiting character is found (where the delimiting character by itself not included in the output parameter). If you don't supply a delimiter (like for example calling the method with only 2 arguments: the `char*` and number of characters to read, as you do for `Name`), then it defaults to new line (`'\n'`). Which means that when you call `infile.get(Name, 15);` it actually reads 14 characters (and we don't expect any new lines in the name, so this means it will always  read exactly 14 characters from the text file), instead of 15 you want. So you need to declare your `Name` to 16 characters and call `infile.get(Name, 16);`. This way you will read 15 characters instead of 14. A *null character* is automatically appended at the end of the input sequence (ie at **index** 15 because we know 15 characters will be read), so you won't need to worry about that. So the fact that removing the `'#'` character from the names yourself means that you automatically make each name 14 characters long, instead of 15, so that explains why `infile.get(Name, 15);` would succeed in such scenario.
2. Another thing to note is that you should probably ignore the column separator character between columns `Roll_no` and `Name`. This character is probably a space or a tab (`'\t'`) in your text file. Use `istream::ignore` method (just before reading `Name`) to ignore a single character, by calling it like so: `infile.ignore();`.
3. Watch your `skipg` call and the file encoding. Are you sure it's 40 characters? For me it was 39 and this is something that will really depend on the contents of your file. You can maybe try out `istream::getline`, or `getline`, or `ignore` as alternatives to ignore the first line.

#### Summarizing edit 1:

1. Change your private properties of each `Student` to be:

```
private:
    char Name[16]; //Changed to 16 characters long, instead of 15.
    char Roll_no[9]; //Changed to 9 characters long, instead of 8.
    int Serial_no, FSC_marks, Entry_test_marks;
```

2. Change your reading of each `Student` from the file to be:

```
void Read(fstream& infile)
{
    infile >> Serial_no;
    infile >> Roll_no; //'\n' is automatically appended.
    infile.ignore(); //Added this line to ignore the column separator between the number Roll_no and the Name.
    infile.get(Name, 16); //Changed to read 15 characters instead of 14. '\n' is automatically appended.
    infile >> FSC_marks >> Entry_test_marks;
}
```

3. Play around with the argument of `skipg` (or count the characters yourself).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem with the constructor. I have fixed it but it still doesn't work like it's suppose to.I am probably reading the file wrong but i don't get it. However, if i remove the '#' character from the names, it works almost perfectly. Any idea why so?

Comment: Please read my **Edit 1** and **Summarizing edit 1** sections.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and helping me solve this.